# SharePoint 2013 CSS - Move around global navigation elements

Tags: css, sharepoint, navigation

I'd like to be able to move the Global Navigation Bar above or below the "suite bar" in SP 2013.

Here is an example of what it would look like:

[image: Example]

I know I could add a div in the master page, however, I would like to just use CSS. Would I use #DeltaTopNavigation or ms-breadcrumb-top?  What CSS properties would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to move the designer bar down to give room for the nav

```
#ms-designer-ribbon{
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Be sure to un-hide s4-titlerow.  If you don't, the nav will disappear when you use the ribbon.

```
#s4-titlerow {
    display: inline!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#DeltaTopNavigation
{
// you can move with "margin-top:**px;" 

}
```

I pulled this form --> http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/branding-top-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-top"> - this div is the outer wrapping div that spans the width of the navigation area in the OOTB seattle.master. In a custom branding scenario, you probably will use your own wrapping div instead of this one.

    <div class="ms-core-navigation"> - This tag is the wrapping div of the top navigation link area. Not much going on here for styling purposes.

    <div class= "ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox" > - Second wrapping div sets the display of the nav to render inline-block. 

    <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static"> - top level of the list. The "root" class provides an easy way to identify the root of your navigation and apply any nedessary styles, while the "static" class is applied to any element of the navigation that doesn't dynamically appear (e.g., dropdown navigation).  The .ms-core-listMenu-root class sets the margin to zero.

    <li class="static"> - an item in the navigation list. Again the "static" tag is applied to the top level navigation items because they are static and don't dynamically appear/disappear based on interaction. 

    <a class="static menu-item"> - the "menu-item" class denotes that this is one of the actual links in the navigation. Styles that affect the actual link are generally applied at this level of the navigation structure.

    <span class="additional-background"> - this span gives you an extra layer to apply additional styling if necessary.

    <span class="menu-item-text"> - the span that holds the actual text. Generally, you probably won't need to do much with this, as most styles for the navigation links actually take place on the "menu-item" class applied at the <a> tag level.
```

Comment: yes, thank you, that's helpful.  However, I'm looking for the specific rule / method in CSS to move some of these elements above or below other ones.

Comment: `#DeltaTopNavigation
{
top: 0px; 

}` puts the nav bar on the same level as the suite bar (the top).  Doing something like `top: -20px` puts it under it, but if I want the width to stretch across the whole browser, it covers the "share, follow" stuff on the right.  How can I actually move it / put it on its own line like in image?

Comment: try adding--> z-index:-1;  It should let the share and follow hover on top.